# Add values from one column to another based on a reference [Excel]

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to find out the best way to solve this;

I have two excel sheets. 
Sheet1 
Col A    Col B 
Item No  Selling Price
This Sheet1 has about 10,000 Entries.

Sheet2 
Col A    Col B 
Item No  Selling Price 
This Sheet2 has about 5,000 Entries. The 5,000 Entries here have the same Item No as Sheet1 with different Selling Price that I need to update in sheet1.

So I basically want to find all the 5,000 items of Sheet2 in Sheet1 and then update the selling price in Sheet1 with the values in Sheet2.

Sheet1 
-0001  45.45 
-0002  34.23 
-0003  23.23 
-0004  37.32

Sheet2 
-0001  56.34 
-0002  95.43

Sheet1 should finally look like so; 
-0001  56.34 
-0002  95.43 
-0003  23.23 
-0004  37.32 

**Additional notes; the Records in both sheets are not in the same order as to how I have displayed above.

They are more like; 
Sheet1 
-0001  45.45 
-0003  23.23 
-0002  34.23 
-0004  37.32

Sheet2 
-0002  95.43 
-0001  56.34

Sheet1
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2
[image: Sheet2]

Comment: This can easily be done in a helper column with an [index match](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/) combination.

Comment: You can just use forumla to check if item no is in table from sheet 2 if yes, then vlookup it and return price, if it's not there then just pick price from shhet1.
Then just copy and paste values into sheet1 column B : )
 Formula would look close to : if(vlookup(itemno.1, $blocked range of sheet2 $,2,False)=True, vlookup(itemno.1, $blocked range of sheet2 $,2,False),itemno1price)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put this in sheet1 column C (or any empty column) and drag down the fill handle it will give you the updated prices:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"")
```

Then you can merge the two columns.

**EDIT**
an easy way to merge the two is to update the formula like so:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)),O1)
```

Drag down again, select whole column and paste values over column B where your prices were.

Comment: In my sheet2 the Item No is in columnA and Prices in columnB however, in my sheet1 the Item No is in columnA but the Price is in columnO.

Comment: Change the `Sheet2!B:B` to `Sheet2!O:O` and it should do the same.

Comment: @mysamza did you get no hits at all? That shouldn't be possible, at least it should have filled with the values from sheet1 column B. The text type shouldn't be an issue. Are you sure you have the right column letters? Do you have hidden columns? Did you drag the fill handle down to the end of your data?

Comment: I have added the screenshot of my Sheet1 and Sheet2 in the original post body.

Comment: I don't see any correlation between the product numbers in sheet1 and the ones in sheet2. Are you sure there are matching values that are formatted the same?

Comment: These in the screenshot are just couple in the beginning which yes don't look like they are related but there are records from Sheet1 that are in Sheet2 and vice versa. Also trying to understand =IFNA(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!O:O,0)),"") There is no ColumnO in Sheet2. I think I messed something up..

Comment: I see, you stated your column O was on sheet 2, but it's in sheet 1 instead. I've updated the second formula in my answer, this should do the trick now, and populate with the standard prices on sheet1 if no price is available on sheet2.

Comment: Hey thanks a ton for taking your time out to help me on this, also sorry but I never said it was in sheet 2.. 'in my sheet1 the Item No is in columnA but the Price is in columnO' it did populate now in the Column EF I put your code in however the values are incorrect.

Comment: Yes I notice now I misread your first comment, that's on me sorry. Also if the values are incorrect, please note that this starts counting from row 1. If you insert it below a header (row 2) then all the values are mismatched by 1 row. Start your formula on row 2 like so: `=IFNA(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),O2)`

Comment: yep! this worked! Thanks a lot once again!